# ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, camera, screenshot

I try to test a demo to upload a recorded video 
I get this error :

```
ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
```

i use this demo :
[uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

I can record a video but when I click save to go to other Activity for Uplading file, i get the error above

the error is here by OnCreate :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

    // Changing action bar background color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
                    R.color.action_bar))));

    // Receiving the data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

    // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
    boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

    if (filePath != null) {
        // Displaying the image or video on the screen
        previewMedia(isImage);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server
            new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error after deleting this line for color :

```
//getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
                R.color.action_bar))));
```